# Background-image in div not repeating?

Tags: html, css, image, divide

I'm having trouble getting an image to repeat in HTML/CSS. I'm very new to this so I might have made a basic mistake but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

I've made a div in my index.html

```
    ...
  <body>
     <div class="bakgrund"></div>
  </body>
    ...
```

And my CSS-file:

```
    .bakgrund {
  background-image: url("img/bakgrund.png");
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

The image is displayed but only once. What I want to do is for the image to repeat vertically and horizontally. This works perfectly when I define the background image in the body tag and not as a div, is it possible?

Comment: Is your image taller/wider than 200px?

Comment: It's actually exactly 200px wide and 200px tall, does that change anything?

Comment: 200px is not very wide. Did you want the background to repeat all over the body rather than just one smallish div?

Comment: It can not repeat itself on this size, because it already has this size of the ```div```.

Comment: Ohhh now I get it! I want it to repeat itself all over the body but it can't since it's already inside a fixed div.. Would a good solution be to make the div for example 10x larger, to fit 10 images?

Comment: If you want to make that image smaller, you can add a percentage value for example: ```background-size: 10%```. Also, you do not need to add ```repeat``` as it is the default value.

Answer (score 2):

If your background image size large than div size please set the background size like this.

```css
.bakgrund {
    background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
     <div class="bakgrund"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: The default value of `background-repeat` is already repeat

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was thinking as well.. I tried to explicitly add it but didn't work either

Comment: I think your image can be larger than 200px

Comment: If that It can't be repeated

Comment: It will make no difference adding this. Not only is repeat the default but also the div it is being applied to is quite possibly as small or smaller than the image.

Comment: @pinkRobot435 If your background image large than div size, set the backgournd-size in css. I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, after I added it all in the comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

The default value of background-repeat is already repeating but if if you need to repeat the background image by css in ...?
**try this**

```
.bakgrund {
    background: url("img/bakgrund.png") repeat;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: As repeat is the default the answer here does not add anything.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your CSS file

```
background-repeat: repeat;
```

Comment: The default value of background-repeat is already repeat